# Docker Postgres database corrupted

Tags: postgresql, docker, timescaledb

I had a docker container running timescaleDB. The database data was stored outside the container.

```
docker run -d --name timescale -v /<DATA>:/var/lib/postgresql/data timescale/timescaledb-postgis:latest-pg10
```

Something strange happened lately. I log in and see all the databases have suddenly vanished

I see the below in the log file

```
2021-03-13 11:32:00.215 UTC [21] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2021-03-11 16:16:19 UTC
2021-03-13 11:32:00.242 UTC [21] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
2021-03-13 11:32:00.243 UTC [21] LOG:  redo starts at 0/15C1270
2021-03-13 11:32:00.243 UTC [21] LOG:  invalid record length at 0/15C12A8: wanted 24, got 0
2021-03-13 11:32:00.243 UTC [21] LOG:  redo done at 0/15C1270
2021-03-13 11:32:00.247 UTC [8] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2021-03-13 20:33:10.424 UTC [31] LOG:  could not receive data from client: Operation timed out
2021-03-13 20:33:10.424 UTC [29] LOG:  could not receive data from client: Operation timed out
```

Does that means that database has corrupted? If so is there a way to recover it somehow? The container has been running for 3 years without a problem and suddenly this unexpected loss of database.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the database was corrupted, but it was recovering by the automated recovery process. It looked like the db system started working since it sent this message: `database system is ready to accept connections`. This means that the logfile recovery was done properly (which doesn't mean that the database files are fully consistent).

When the database is abruptly shutdown, there is small chance for filelvel corruption as well, but the good news is that I don't see anything in the log, after the recovery that can suggest that this is the case, however, you need to have backup of the files.

The next log message `could not receive data from client: Operation timed out` is not related to recovery, it's due to the client application which had terminated without properly closing the connection.

Check more information on corruptions and reasons in [Postgresql wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Corruption).

If you depend on the data in the database, always keep backup. Easiest way is to use `pg_dumpall`. This will dump the data in plain text format as a series of SQL statements and you will be able to import the data on later versions of `PostgreSQL`.

So my recommendation, before you do anything else with it, **STOP THE CONTAINER AND TAKE BACKUP OF THE FILES**. The recovery is trial and error process, and you will need to have the fresh copy of the files to try different thing. After you do this, export the data with `pg_dumpall`. If this passes, you can resume normal operations of the database.

Comment: thanks for your answer. After zipping my data folder, the zip file is only 5MB, though the database which now seems to be vanished ran into GB's  Does this mean filesystem is corrupted?

Comment: I don't believe that the filesystem is corrupted, it's very rare case when there was power-off on slow USB disks, but you can scan the host disks to see if there are issues with the filesystem. Each OS has it's own way for scanning, so you can search for your OS. Be careful with linux tools, some of them will unmount the fs for the check which will interrupt your services.

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply. Just one more thing.. my disk on which database was mounted was 100GB, if for some reason the disk space got 100% full, the postgres shouldn't crash and erase all the data right? Just wondering..

Comment: postresql will not erase data if the disk is full. Depending on what is on the disk, postgresql will stop serving clients, or if the disk contains the log files (WAL files) postgresql will enter panic mode and shut down the database.

Comment: Actually, the logs that I posted are not from immediate crash. As result of a panic, after discovering that database was gone, I stopped restarted the docker container, hoping to recover the loss but it seemed to have permanently disappeared. And I didn't save the logs . It was something very similar to the logs in my question. Some block of data was not available

Comment: sometimes, if docker tries to stop applications that do not respond, it will use `kill -9` to bring them down by force. If your database was busy when you ware stopping it, the dtbase will not have stopped before the timeout, so docker moved and killed it. This will explain the `not properly shut down` message you see in the log. Use `docker stop -t 3600 <dbcontainer>` to wait 1 hour before kill is initiated